# Issues with SPFilterDropdown in SPD2013

Tags: javascript, filter, dropdown, sharepoint-designer

To start things, I have little knowledge beyond the basic concepts of SPD and being a newbie...

What I want to accomplish is to only have certain values from another list show up in which their corresponding value for active is "Yes". I've created a custom Edit Form in which I placed the code, however I keep coming up with the error: 
`Web Part Error: Unknown server tag. Correlation ID: 3dd8e69c-6dfb-4014-b243-46b1a8039de1.`

Am I inserting the code in the wrong section of the code? Not sure where to go from here, any input help! Thanks!

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../../Pages/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../../Pages/js/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown({
          relationshipList: "Standard Bulletin Reviewers Lookup",
          relationshipListColumn: "Title",
          columnName: "StdReviewer1",
          CAMLQuery: "<Eq><FieldRef Name='Active'/><Value Type='Text'>Yes</Value></Eq>",
          completefunc: null,
          debug: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SPServices in your edit form make sure it is placed after:

`<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">`

In a custom form it should be located shortly after the listings of the fields in the code.

Comment: So I've added that to the beginning of the code as well as </asp:Content> to the end with no luck and continue getting an error. I'm placing this slice of code after </WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart> and before </ZoneTemplate>. I've tried placing immediately after the all my fields that are enclosed with <tr> and </tr>. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: You are placing this in your custom form's `.aspx` right?  You shouldn't have to add the `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">`, it should already be there.  Run a find for that tag in your file and see if it's there.

Comment: It should be after `</WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>` like you mentioned but not before `</ZoneTemplate>`.  It should be a few lines after that.

Comment: I placed it there, and I'm no longer getting any error, but the code doesn't take any effect when editing the item...

Comment: Under `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">` there's also: `<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="FormCustomRedirectControl" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
 <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
  <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>
 </ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>`

Comment: Yep, that's the correct place to put it.  I generally place it the line after `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">`.  If there's no effect then make sure the jQuery and SPServices libraries are referenced correctly (the `src=` is pointing in the right spot).

Comment: It worked! I tried placing it under: `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">` and it took. Thanks for the help Jordan :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked out!